How to restrict access to services on different ports by IP and allow by domain? Nginx, Linux, Docker
On my server (with a single IP address), several services are running on different ports.
Nginx is also running on ports 80 and 443 to serve pages upon domain requests.
All services and nginx are launched via docker-compose.
How can I reject all external requests to the IP address (for example, to 56.56.56.56:3000 or to 56.56.56.56) but at the same time allow all requests to domain names using nginx, iptables, firewall, and other development tools?
Everything is running on Ubutntu server 22.04
nginx.conf
http {
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=5r/s;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name my.domain www.my.domain;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name my.domain;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my.domain/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my.domain/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        client_body_timeout 10s;
        client_header_timeout 10s;
        keepalive_timeout 10s;
        send_timeout 10s;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://56.56.56.56:3002; # адрес для примера
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 10;
            limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=10 nodelay;
        }
    }
    ...
}

docker-compose.yml
...
  site:
    build:
      context: ...
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "1m"
        max-file: "1"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana
...

Thanks in advance!
Important info

If I try to restrict external TCP requests through iptables and allow only internal ones (so that requests can only be sent from outside via nginx, i.e., to the domain name), the firewall blocks even the requests going through nginx. I thought that when sending requests to domains, they are routed through nginx, so the firewall considers the request to be sent from the local IP.

If I run all services locally on the machine (for example, app.run("127.0.0.1", port=3000)), nginx doesn’t detect this, meaning proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000 won’t work.I was thinking of running all services locally so that they couldn’t be accessed directly from the outside, but nginx could still access them since it’s running in the same container, but only through domain requests. However, for some reason, I get a “connection refused” error when nginx tries to request 127.0.0.1.



You don't need to publish the ports at all (except nginx of course). You can have nginx access the other services internally by their name, e.g. http://grafana:3000.

Your container networking exposes unnecessary host ports.

Remove the external ports from docker-compose.yml for everything but the external proxy, in this case named nginx.
Keep these frontend and backend containers in the same docker-compose  network.
Use names for containers to refer to each other on the network. proxy_pass to backends  http://site:3002  and http://grafana:3000

Resulting in your container definition also generating a firewall with a zone concept. Containers can reach each other, but external host traffic only going in the port to nginx. Extra manually generated private networking and firewall rules are not required to implement this isolation.
This IP level networking and firewall does not care about your http name virtual hosts. However that nginx configuration already requires names at the application level. And the https redirect will have user agents also validating the name.  (Certificates with IP address subjects are theoretically possible but approximately no one uses them versus (DNS) names.)
Not specifying IP addresses gives your address plan more flexibility.

If the reverse proxy was not via a loopback address, the containers could run on different hosts.
When you implement IPv6 addresses, you no longer need to worry about address space overlap. All the space you should use is internet routable, but that's fine.  The difference between container address of say 2001:db8:116:7483::a  and ::b could be that one exposes host ports and one doesn't.

